# ArcGIS Pro and Map Clipping

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, clip

I am trying to create a map with an extent that followings the lines of latitude and longitude in a Canada Lambert Conformal Conic projection, similar to the one below:

[image: Map Image]

However, if I set the clip extent under the map (Map > Clip Layers > Custom Extent), it just creates a square, which under this projection does not follow the specified lines of lat or lon. I am wondering how I can get it to clip while following the specified lines of lat and lon similar to that shown in the attached image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue is in the word, extent.  Extent is the "bounding box" to the display which of cause is a rectangle.  So you are clipping back to the rectangle, the "custom" part is that the rectangle can be of any size.

You need to be clipping back to a shape in the same projection. I loaded up from living atlas the provinces of Canada and dissolved and told the map to clip back to the **outline** and I get this result when displaying a graticule in a layout.

[image]

Comment: That look great, and thanks for the clarification that "extent" is based on the rectangle shape. I am going to mark this as answered, but can you further describe the process of the clip? I am assuming you would need to make a new polygon, as you stated in the same projection, and potentially create the polygon based on coordinates and then clip the original layer to that?

Comment: I created a national boundary of Canada by dissolving the provinces and ensured that was in the Canada Lambert Conformal Conic projection. That is the clipping outline I referenced in the maps clipping properties. I did not use it to actually clip the other datasets. That's the whole point of the map doing the clip you don't need to alter the other datasets if the purpose is for display only. You would want to actually clip the data if you were doing analysis so for example you get correct areas.